# VueJS and Canva Button JS API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using Canva's Button JS API that's based here - https://www.canva.com/button/documentation/js-api/

I am trying to implement a modular approach on using their API. I only load the CanvaJS when it's needed. So they way i implement it is when a button is clicked. This is how I approached it.

This is my `index.vue` or my vue file.

```
import CanvaService from '@app/services/canva';
...

<button class="btn btn-primary" @click.prevent="drawCanva()">Click Here!</button>
...
methods : {
 drawCanva() {
   CanvaService.load();
 },
}
```

This is what's inside my `canva.js` or `CanvaService`

```
class CanvaService {

    constructor (config) {
        this.api_key = "XXXXX XXXX";
        this.api = "";
        this.has_init = false;
    }

    load() {
        let _this = this;
        if(!_this.has_init) {
            (function (document, url) {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.src = url;
                script.onload = function () {
                    _this.init();
                };
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            })(document, 'https://sdk.canva.com/v2/beta/api.js');
        } else {
            _this.createDesign();
        }


    }

    init() {
        let _this = this;
        (async function () {
            if (window.CanvaButton) {
                if (!_this.has_init) {
                    _this.api = await window.CanvaButton.initialize({
                        apiKey: _this.api_key
                    });

                    _this.has_init = true;
                    _this.createDesign();
                } else {
                    _this.createDesign();
                }
            }
        })();
    }

    createDesign() {
        this.api.createDesign({
            type: 'Poster',
            onDesignOpen: ({ designId }) => {
                // Triggered when editor finishes loading and opens a new design.
                // You can save designId for future use.
            },
            onDesignPublish: ({ exportUrl, designId }) => {
                console.log("onDesignPublish");
                console.log(exportUrl);
                return exportUrl;
            }
        });
    }
}

export default new CanvaService ();
```

To be honest, i'm not really good with Javascript, so I am not sure if this is the proper way of doing a modular approach. My question here are 2 things:

1. Is this the correct way of making this a modular approach?
2. How can I return the value of `exportUrl` in my `index.vue` file?

Any help or tips, please? Your help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can change your Service class to a mixin, so you will be able to touch the right "this" when you call your methods :)

Mixins docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html

2 - using a mixing you will be able to save your URL inside the Vue component data.

```
createDesign() {
    this.api.createDesign({
        type: 'Poster',
        onDesignOpen: ({ designId }) => {
            // Triggered when editor finishes loading and opens a new design.
            // You can save designId for future use.
        },
        onDesignPublish: ({ exportUrl, designId }) => {
            console.log("onDesignPublish");
            console.log(exportUrl);
            this.myExportedURL = exportUrl;
        }
    });
}
```